# Docker - nodejs - Loosing nodeapp folder on mounting volume

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-volume

I have a `nodejs` docker image. When I run it with the following command :

```
docker run -p 8443:9845 myimage
```

I get the container as expected with nodeapp folder in /app folder. But when I start the docker with mounted volume like this :

```
docker run -v /opt/data:/app -p 8443:9845 myimage
```

I get the mounted volume contents, but nothing in my nodeapp folder. Anyone faced such an issue before ?

Comment: I honestly don't know if it is required, but... did you declared the volume `VOLUME /app` in the Dockerfile used to create the the image?

Comment: Can you show us the content of your nodeapp folder after applying bind mount? Also kindly show us `ls /opt/data` Because your command looks fine

Comment: You're telling Docker to hide everything in `/app` and overwrite it with arbitrary content from the host.  There's no way to "merge" host and image content.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Yes, that's what was happening. Thank you. Could you please post it as an answer for others as well.